# What do these dual DC rating numbers on my Casio PB-2000C mean?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc, ratings, dual

All devices I own except one have only one rating that matches what the PSU says, for example "12V ⎓ 2.5A" and that means if I have to get a replacement PSU it has to be 12V and at least 2.5A (and also matching polarity and tip size, not important for this question).

This one says "9V,3V ⎓ 0.09W" and I can't find anything like that on the web. I don't know much about electronics, I tried searching but came up with nothing useful. The [original PSU](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Casio_AD-4175) (which I don't own and I can't find for sale) was also rated differently than the numbers printed there, it was 7V 800mAh.

Do those numbers mean I can plug anything between 3V and 9V as long as it provides enough mAh and the polarity and adapter's tip size match? Are the minimum required mAh going to be different depending on how many V my PSU provides? (I suspect that could be the case since it shows 0.09W instead of the usual A or mAh that my other devices show but my knowledge is very limited).

This is an old, difficult to find device so I don't want to risk burning it. I have a 9V 1.2A PSU from another device with matching tip size and polarity.

[image: Picture of the back of the device, indicating this rating: DC 9V,3V 0.09W]

Comment: It appears this writing appears on the device not the power supply, right? Which Casio product is it?

Comment: Yes, the writing is on the device. It's [this Casio calculator](https://www.rskey.org/pb2000c).  [This page](http://www.pisi.com.pl/piotr433/index.htm#pb2000) has the service manual in PDF format in case you need it, it has data sheets and other things I don't understand that may help.

Comment: There's also different information about the PSU depending on where you read. The page I linked says 9VDC, the back of the Casio says "9V,3V", the owner's manual says it uses an AD-4175 (that is 7V) and the service manual mentions an AD-4175J (this can be a printing error because I can't find any information about it).

Comment: IF the supply or socket have 3 connections ot MAY be a dual supply, providing both 9V and 3V siultaneously. This is rare but dies happen. If there are only two connections then "more investigation is in order".

Comment: That "straight line with dashed line below it" is the DC symbol, and it's in unicode: ⎓

Comment: Thank you, I'll replace my text description with the proper character. I didn't know it was in Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device requires both 9 V and 3 V supplies. It is quite likely that the 3 V supply is to maintain the program memory while the processor is switched off.

- The CR2032 coin cells are 3 V, lithium, 20 mm and the device uses three. Since 9 V is required the cells must be in series.
- The CR1220 cell is a 3 V, lithium, 12 mm cell.
- The power rating is the product of volts × amperes so if we assume all the power requirement is at 9 V then the current drawn while on will be 0.01 A (10 mA).

[image]

*Figure 1. The power-supply circuit. (Double-click for full resolution.)*

- (1) The 9 V supply.
- (2) The 3 V battery positive is connected rather unusually to the 9 V via  diode. This seems to generate VLCD (5) at around 6 V.
- (3) and (4) Common VDD.
- (5) VLCD.
- I suspected that when using the mains adaptor that the 3 V supply is derived from the 9 V supply. Looking at the schematic it appears that this is not the case and that the LCD relies in part on the CR1220.

[Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1496885.pdf) rates the CR2023 at 210 mAh at 20℃ under 15kΩ load (0.2 mA) to 2.0V end-voltage. 210 mAh suggests 21 h at 10 mA but I would have expected it to be a lot less. Surprisingly the [manual](http://www.pisi.com.pl/piotr433/manuals/pb2000sm.pdf) says that battery life is approximately 25 hours (continuous program execution) and 35 hours (continuous display of 5555555555 at 20°C) which is delightfully specific. Memory backup battery is rated at 2 years.

---

Something I learned while writing this:

```
CR2032                  CR1220
C = Lithium             C = Lithium
 R = Round               R = Round
  20 = 20 mm              12 = 12 mm
    32 = 3.2 mm high        20 = 2.0 mm high
```

I suspect that many are as ignorant as I was regarding the dangers of lithium cell ingestion. While not related to the question I reckon it's worth spreading the knowledge:

**Ingestion**

> Lithium cells, if ingested, are highly dangerous. In the pediatric population, of particular concern is the potential for one of these batteries to get stuck in the oesophagus. Such impactions can rapidly devolve and cause severe tissue injury in as little as two hours. The damage is not caused by the contents of the battery, but by the electric current that is created when the anode (negative) face of the battery comes in contact with the electrolyte-rich esophageal tissue. The surrounding water undergoes a hydrolysis reaction that produces a sodium hydroxide (caustic soda) build-up near the battery's anode face (cathodic reaction in the electrolyte). This results in the liquefactive necrosis of the tissue, a process whereby the tissue effectively is melted away by the alkaline solution. Severe complications can occur, such as erosion into nearby structures like the trachea or major blood vessels, the latter of which can cause fatal bleeds.

> While the only cure for an esophageal impaction is endoscopic removal, a 2018 study from Children's Hospital of Philadelphia by Rachel R. Anfang and colleagues found that early and frequent ingestion of honey or sucralfate suspension prior to removal can reduce the injury severity to a significant degree. As a result of these findings, US-based National Capital Poison Center (Poison Control) updated its triage and treatment guideline for button battery ingestions to include the administration of honey and/or sucralfate as soon as possible after a known or suspected ingestion.

*Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell#Lithium).*

Comment: Are you sure it requires both? Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfo-blARHsU not seeing an AC adapter plugged into it. This video shows the AC adaptor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPrUN5PyMo

Comment: I don't know how that didn't occur to me. Yes, the manual says the CR1220 is for maintaining the program memory. So would it be safe to use my 9V 1.2A PSU? I'm assuming I read [this](https://www.msx.org/wiki/images/thumb/6/69/Casio_AD-4175_220V.jpg/200px-Casio_AD-4175_220V.jpg) properly and the PSU is center/tip negative, but it says 7V unlike the back of the calculator. I'm going to accept this answer since it answers the main question.

Comment: According to texts in service manual, the CR1220 is used for memory backup, but according to schematics, the CR1220 is used for LCD supply, not for memory backup at all.

Comment: @Justme. That's a strange setup. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: only 10mA is needed, just make a resistive divider from 9V. , 27 ohms and 100 ohms  should be close enough to 7V.

Answer (score 3):

Over at manualslib.com I found the [user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/download/777049/Casio-Pb-2000c.html), and it had to say this about the power supplies:

[image]

Since a CR2032 could be as high as 3.3V, I think it is safe to use a 9V power supply with the device. But since it also works with the AD-4175 you should be able to use a lower voltage supply as well.

With these kinds of devices there is not a great risk of damage if you supply too little voltage, so I would first start with a 7V supply and see if that works.

Comment: I don't have the original 7V supply and that's what made me ask this question in the first place, I only have a 9V. I can get a 7.5V supply though. I can't accept two answers and the other one answered the question I put in the title so I selected it, but thank you for answering my other question.

Comment: A 9V supply seems good if it's regulated - connect a voltmeter and if it reads less than 9.1V  it's good.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll get a voltmeter and test that.

Comment: I got a voltmeter, it reads a constant -9.30V, I'm not sure if the extra -0.2 is good. To make sure I was doing things correctly I also tested another 9V switching PSU and it reads -9.27, and I tested one 9V PSU that uses a transformer, that one read between -12 and -12.22 and was less stable with the numbers. All are center negative so I'm getting all negative numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Back in the 90s very few wallwarts were regulated. The AD-4175 looks like a simple transformer wallwart which wasn't regulated. These adaptors would have a higher output voltage than their rating when unloaded. So, if the Casio accepts a common DC plug -- like a 5.5mm x 2.5mm or a 5.5mm x 2.1mm  plug -- then Casio would have to worry about the user using a "9V" adapter from another product. The way to protect against that would be to use a plug with special dimensions so that only the Casio adapter would fit.

Comment: Furthermore, consider that a fresh CR2032 battery could be as high as 3.3V, so internally the unit has to deal with voltages at least as high as 10V. I think, though, that the device will work with lower voltages maybe down to 8.5V, so you might try a lower voltage adapter. Or you could even try a somewhat depleted 9V battery. Bottom line -- I think a 9.3 regulated voltage would be a very low risk.

Comment: From my rough measurements using a ruler (not the appropriate tool for the job) it is 5.5mm 2.5mm. Thank you for all the great advice. Sorry for replying so late, I don't know how notifications work here but I didn't get them for your replies, I had to come back to the question and check.

Answer (score 0):

So the device reads like that because it can be powered wih either batteries or power supply model AD-4175.

When it is battery powered, it has a 9V main supply from three 3V CR2032 batteries, and a singe 3V CR1220 for other purposes. According to manuals, it is used for memory backup supply. Except that in the service manual schematics the CR1220 is not used for memory backup, but as part of LCD supply voltages.

Simplifying a bit, basically the main batteries and the AC adapter voltage supply are just connected together with diodes so highest voltage supply wins to power the circuit, so all that the mains adapter has to do is to provide voltage that is higher than the 9V main battery voltage.

Which now brings up to the circuit analysis part.

The voltage is fed to a 5V regulator which has a absolute maximum input voltage of 12V, typical input voltage range seems to be up to 10V. There is also a 100uF tantalum capacitor but we don't know the voltage rating for it, so it might be 10V or 16V part.

So this means that the AC adapter must provide a voltage that's higher than 9V but not much over 10V for safe margin. There is a voltage drop of one diode from AC adapter, an voltage drop of two diodes from batteries when AC adapter is connected, so AC adapter output can be also slightly less than battery voltage.

The manufacturer also works with the principle of "buy this type of adapter and it will work" because it's easier for them when they manufacture a lot of different devices and AC adapters for them.

So the 7V printed on the adapter can't be the regulated output DC voltage, as it could not provide higher voltage than the batteries. It must mean that it's the unregulated average voltage, when 800mA is drawn from it. This makes more sense, as the unregulated voltage could be approximated to go up to near 10V with very litte load.

So my conclusion is, a regulated 9V DC supply is fine, but it must be a regulated 9V supply, or the unregulated 9V voltage with no load is too high and can damage the device.

Comment: Thank you for analyzing the schematics so well, I don't know which information is reliable anymore. So to test whether the manual or the schematics are right: if I remove the 3 CR2032 and the memory doesn't get erased, could that mean the schematics are wrong? I haven't tried that yet, I'll try later and reply with the results.

Comment: The only way to figure out is to look at if the PCB matches to schematic or description. The device will most likely consume very little current, so maybe the capacitors inside it can keep the voltage large enought to keep memory contents during the few seconds you change the batteries.

Comment: I forgot to keep that in mind. I'll test if my PSU is regulated the way someone in the comments suggested. I don't want to take everything apart and risk messing up, I just want a way to use this as an everyday device without having to be constantly worrying about the batteries.